# Delete Savepoint in ORACLE server

Tags: sql, oracle

I understand that a `savepoint` in `Oracle` SQL identifies a point in a transaction to which you can later `rollback`.

So technically if I create a `savepoint` now and performs 100 manipulations on the DB, I can `rollback` to before those 100 manipulations.

But what if now I don't want to track my changes and delete the savepoint?

thanks

Comment: You don't need to delete the savepoint. I will go away automatically once you commit your transaction

Comment: Also, make sure you are not under the misapprehension that savepoints are somehow consuming a lot a resources.  They are not, for example, a complete saved version of your table data at a given point in time.  They're just a marker so that Oracle can restore the database state as of a given point in time, using UNDO resources that it must hold for the transaction anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As commented by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name), there is no syntax in Oracle to delete a savepoint.

When you `COMMIT` or a `ROLLBACK` the transaction, the savepoints are automatically deleted.

From [the Oracle docs on Transaction Control](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/transact.htm#CNCPT1118) :

> The `COMMIT` statement ends the current transaction and makes all changes performed in the transaction permanent. **`COMMIT` also erases all savepoints in the transaction** and releases transaction locks.
>
> The `ROLLBACK` statement reverses the work done in the current transaction; it causes all data changes since the last `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` to be discarded.

You may also want to modify your code to not create savepoints.

Answer (score -1):

Commit (or rollback), and then remove savepoint from your code.